# How do I group data to have a similar range of levels?

Tags: r, clustering

## Background

I am working on a procurement bid where we are purchasing a number of different vehicle types for our various locations.  As part of the analysis, I want to plot the prices of vehicle type vs. location, and due to the large number of locations (40) and vehicle types (18), I broke them up into 5 separate plots that are facet wrapped (single row).  Initially, I just order the data by the max bid price and split the data into 8 location per plot which resulted in an imbalance demonstrated here by 2 of the 5 plots I made:

#### Plot with 6 vehicle types

[image: 6 vehicle types]

#### Plot with 14 vehicle types

[image: 14 vehicle types]

## Data

The data that I'm plotting looks like below...

```
> df_bids
# A tibble: 418 × 4
   location company  vehicle_type bid_price
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>            <dbl>
 1 LOC01    Company1 VT01             21483
 2 LOC01    Company2 VT01             17932
 3 LOC01    Company3 VT01             21128
 4 LOC01    Company4 VT01             18190
 5 LOC01    Company1 VT02             21192
 6 LOC01    Company2 VT02             17294
 7 LOC01    Company3 VT02             21446
 8 LOC01    Company4 VT02             18087
 9 LOC01    Company2 VT03             25212
10 LOC01    Company3 VT03             32160
# ℹ 408 more rows
```

...but I think that's a lot of data to post here in Stack Exchange (I'm happy to post it if necessary), and I think my problem only really cares about the location and vehicle type:

```
library(tidyverse)

> df_contingency <- df_bids %>% 
+   select(location, vehicle_type) %>% 
+   unique() %>% 
+   print()
# A tibble: 106 × 2
   location vehicle_type
   <chr>    <chr>       
 1 LOC01    VT01        
 2 LOC01    VT02        
 3 LOC01    VT03        
 4 LOC02    VT04        
 5 LOC02    VT05        
 6 LOC02    VT03        
 7 LOC03    VT03        
 8 LOC03    VT06        
 9 LOC04    VT03        
10 LOC05    VT03        
# ℹ 96 more rows
```

So here's the data that I think is most relevant:

```
> dput(df_contingency)
structure(list(location = c("LOC01", "LOC01", "LOC01", "LOC02", 
"LOC02", "LOC02", "LOC03", "LOC03", "LOC04", "LOC05", "LOC06", 
"LOC07", "LOC07", "LOC07", "LOC08", "LOC08", "LOC09", "LOC09", 
"LOC09", "LOC09", "LOC09", "LOC10", "LOC10", "LOC11", "LOC12", 
"LOC12", "LOC12", "LOC12", "LOC13", "LOC14", "LOC14", "LOC15", 
"LOC15", "LOC16", "LOC16", "LOC16", "LOC16", "LOC17", "LOC18", 
"LOC18", "LOC19", "LOC19", "LOC19", "LOC19", "LOC20", "LOC20", 
"LOC20", "LOC20", "LOC21", "LOC21", "LOC21", "LOC21", "LOC21", 
"LOC21", "LOC22", "LOC22", "LOC22", "LOC22", "LOC23", "LOC23", 
"LOC23", "LOC24", "LOC24", "LOC25", "LOC26", "LOC26", "LOC26", 
"LOC26", "LOC26", "LOC26", "LOC26", "LOC27", "LOC27", "LOC27", 
"LOC28", "LOC28", "LOC29", "LOC29", "LOC29", "LOC29", "LOC30", 
"LOC30", "LOC31", "LOC31", "LOC31", "LOC31", "LOC32", "LOC33", 
"LOC33", "LOC33", "LOC34", "LOC34", "LOC35", "LOC35", "LOC35", 
"LOC36", "LOC36", "LOC37", "LOC37", "LOC38", "LOC39", "LOC39", 
"LOC39", "LOC39", "LOC39", "LOC40"), vehicle_type = c("VT01", 
"VT02", "VT03", "VT04", "VT05", "VT03", "VT03", "VT06", "VT03", 
"VT03", "VT03", "VT01", "VT05", "VT06", "VT03", "VT01", "VT03", 
"VT05", "VT01", "VT06", "VT07", "VT01", "VT03", "VT03", "VT06", 
"VT01", "VT05", "VT08", "VT06", "VT06", "VT03", "VT01", "VT03", 
"VT01", "VT03", "VT06", "VT05", "VT03", "VT09", "VT03", "VT10", 
"VT03", "VT06", "VT11", "VT12", "VT13", "VT11", "VT03", "VT13", 
"VT01", "VT06", "VT14", "VT03", "VT15", "VT06", "VT07", "VT11", 
"VT03", "VT04", "VT11", "VT03", "VT03", "VT01", "VT03", "VT03", 
"VT01", "VT16", "VT02", "VT06", "VT05", "VT11", "VT17", "VT01", 
"VT03", "VT03", "VT06", "VT14", "VT06", "VT03", "VT11", "VT06", 
"VT03", "VT01", "VT13", "VT03", "VT10", "VT03", "VT05", "VT01", 
"VT06", "VT03", "VT06", "VT06", "VT01", "VT05", "VT18", "VT06", 
"VT06", "VT05", "VT03", "VT13", "VT05", "VT01", "VT06", "VT03", 
"VT06")), row.names = c(NA, -106L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

## Analysis & Goal

This steps through my (working/hazy) thought process, but my goal is to take 40 locations with varying mixes of 18 vehicle types, and group them into 5 groups of locations where the number of vehicle types in each group is as close to the same number as possible across groups (i.e. the range of vehicle types in any group is between 6 and 8 instead of between 4 and 14).

### Contingency Table (?)

My first thought is to look at the data using contingency table functions:

```
library(tidyverse) # I work in tidyverse and use the magrittr pipe (%>%).

> tbl_contingency <- df_contingency %>% 
+   table()
> 
> addmargins(tbl_contingency)
        vehicle_type
location VT01 VT02 VT03 VT04 VT05 VT06 VT07 VT08 VT09 VT10 VT11 VT12 VT13 VT14 VT15 VT16 VT17 VT18 Sum
   LOC01    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   3
   LOC02    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   3
   LOC03    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC04    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC05    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC06    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC07    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   3
   LOC08    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC09    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   5
   LOC10    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC11    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC12    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   4
   LOC13    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC14    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC15    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC16    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   4
   LOC17    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC18    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC19    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   4
   LOC20    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0   4
   LOC21    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0   6
   LOC22    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   4
   LOC23    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   3
   LOC24    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC25    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC26    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0   7
   LOC27    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   3
   LOC28    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC29    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0   4
   LOC30    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC31    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0   4
   LOC32    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC33    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   3
   LOC34    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC35    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   3
   LOC36    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   2
   LOC37    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2
   LOC38    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   LOC39    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0   5
   LOC40    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   1
   Sum     16    2   32    2   10   21    2    1    1    2    6    1    4    2    1    1    1    1 106

> tbl_contingency %>% 
+   margin.table(margin = 1) %>% 
+   sort(decreasing = TRUE)
location
LOC26 LOC21 LOC09 LOC39 LOC12 LOC16 LOC19 LOC20 LOC22 LOC29 LOC31 LOC01 LOC02 LOC07 LOC23 LOC27 LOC33 LOC35 LOC03 LOC08 LOC10 LOC14 LOC15 LOC18 LOC24 
    7     6     5     5     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     2     2     2     2     2     2     2 
LOC28 LOC30 LOC34 LOC36 LOC37 LOC04 LOC05 LOC06 LOC11 LOC13 LOC17 LOC25 LOC32 LOC38 LOC40 
    2     2     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
> 
> tbl_contingency %>% 
+   margin.table(margin = 2) %>% 
+   sort(decreasing = TRUE)
vehicle_type
VT03 VT06 VT01 VT05 VT11 VT13 VT02 VT04 VT07 VT10 VT14 VT08 VT09 VT12 VT15 VT16 VT17 VT18 
  32   21   16   10    6    4    2    2    2    2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Not being very sophisticated, I looked at LOC26 with 7 vehicle types because I don't want to split a location across multiple groups (I want the locations to only appear once across the 5 groups), the minimum number of groups I'll have for whatever group contains LOC26 is 7.

This lead me to write this (very complicated) code to loop through and group the locations based on matching the location with the most vehicle types (`lead_city`) with the next 7 most matching locations, filtering out those locations from the next iteration and repeating until all locations are grouped.  I tacked on at the end any "ieligible cities" that didn't match at the end to ensure I used up all the locations, but this resulted in a large number of vehicle types in the last group:

```
vec_removed <- character()  
n_count <- 8  # Number of locations to be in each grouping
i <- 1
df_contingency <- add_column(df_contingency, group_assigned = NA)

while (length(vec_removed) < 40){
  
  print(paste("This is start of Loop", i, ":"))
  
  # Remove the locations previously grouped.
  df_contingency2 <- df_contingency %>%   
    filter(!location %in% vec_removed)
  
  # Identify location with most vehicle types this iteration.
  lead_city <- df_contingency2 %>%   
    count(location) %>% 
    arrange(desc(n))
  
  # Identify the vehicle types associated with lead_city
  vec_vehicle_types <- df_contingency2 %>% 
    filter(location == lead_city$location[1]) %>%
    pull(vehicle_type)
  
  # Any location that has vehicle types not matching lead_city is identified
  #   in order to tack on last in the next step below.
  ineligible_cities <- df_contingency2 %>%  
    filter(!vehicle_type %in% vec_vehicle_types) %>%
    group_by(location) %>%
    summarise(vt_matches = length(intersect(vehicle_type, vec_vehicle_types))) %>%
    mutate(type = "ineligible") %>% 
    arrange(desc(vt_matches)) 

  # Remove the non-matching locations from above, sort by the most matches
  #   to the lead_city's vehicle_types, and then tack on the ineligible_cities.
  group_cities <- df_contingency2 %>%  
    filter(!location %in% ineligible_cities$location) %>%  
    count(location) %>%
    arrange(desc(n)) %>%
    bind_rows(ineligible_cities)
  
  # Create the group by grabbing the first 8 locations
  grp <- group_cities$location[seq(n_count)]  

  df_contingency <- df_contingency %>% 
    mutate(group_assigned = if_else(location %in% grp, paste("Group", i), group_assigned))
  
  # Build vector of previously assigned locations so they are removed
  #    in the next iteration.
  vec_removed <- c(vec_removed, grp)

  i <- i + 1
  
}
```

And so my resulting groupings aren't well-balanced:

```
> df_contingency %>% 
+   select(group_assigned, vehicle_type) %>% 
+   unique() %>% 
+   count(group_assigned)
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  group_assigned     n
  <chr>          <int>
1 Group 1            7
2 Group 2            6
3 Group 3            5
4 Group 4            8
5 Group 5           12
```

## Help

I feel that my approach above is excessively complex and not effective.  This would seem to be a clustering problem of some sort and I think my contingency table is pretty basic, but I am not sure where to look for a solution.  Any pointers where to look, how to solve this, identification of the type of problem I'm describing -- any of that would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.